# Connecting to SQL Express Server 2017 with SQL Server Authentication Remotely

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017, logins, sql-server-express

I have two systems that are on the same network. I am able to ping back and forth between these systems with their IP address and with their system names. I have enabled the TCP port 1433 inbound and outbound on both systems. I have enabled TCP in the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

I have created an SQL Server Authentication and have the server on mixed login.

I am able to connect to the server from the system it is running on by using the following:

- Server name: DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS
- Authentication: SQL Server Authentication
- Login: admin

However, if I change the Server name to `tcp:DESKTOP,1433\SQLEXPRESS` I am unable to connect. If I change the Authentication mode back to Windows I am able to connect using the above server name.

This is my first time using SQL and I am very confused why I am having this issue. I would like to be able to connect to this server through TCP so that I may connect to it remotely with another system on the same network. Any information or links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Comments [archived](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90328/discussion-on-question-by-jack-connecting-to-sql-express-server-2017-with-sql-se).

Answer (score 2):

Typically, a default instance will use port 1433, and a named instance will use an arbitrary port in the 49152 to 65535 range. Because SQL Express uses a named instance (even if it is the first and only instance on a server), it will grab an arbitrary high port. So make sure that TCP port 50207 is allowed from your second machine to `Desktop`. And also open UDP 1434, in order for the SQL Browser service to do its job.